# How to resolve the auto build failure error?

Tags: android

So, whenever I open Android Studio, it shows me an error in the Problems Tool Window:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.wireless.android.sdk.stats.IntellijIndexingStats$Index
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.counters.IndexCounters.<clinit>(IndexCounters.java:34)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:94)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.impl.MapReduceIndex.<init>(MapReduceIndex.java:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex$CompilerMapReduceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:248)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.index.CompilerReferenceIndex.<init>(CompilerReferenceIndex.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.<init>(JavaCompilerBackwardReferenceIndex.java:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.backwardRefs.JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.initialize(JavaBackwardReferenceIndexWriter.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.buildStarted(JavaBuilder.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:359)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help me to resolve this error.
Thanks for everybody who helps me.
I have updated all my plugins and Android Studio to the latest version.
I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling android studio.
Edit:- Changing the compiler to eclipse doesn’t work for me.

Comment: Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Yes. I am using this version only.

Comment: Please help me out with this.